Recursive BOM Explosion?
I'm trying to build a program to take a top level Part Number and create a BOM for all components beneath it, of which said components can also be assemblies with components.
Unfortunately I am limited to MS access so I can't build a CTE.
I've started building this out, but I'm getting lost on coming back out of a level once I have recursed into it. See below and comment for where I think I need to do something to return to the starting point?

    Dim Search_Part As String
    Search_Part = "PN1234"
   
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT PARENTPART, ROUTE, SEQUENCENUM, COMPONENT FROM TEST_BomStructure AS BOMqry WHERE PARENTPART = '" & Search_Part & "'")
    Set rsnew = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TEST_BomResult")
    
    Set db = CurrentDb
    
    Dim level As Integer
    
    level = 0
    
    Do Until rs.EOF
        rsnew.AddNew
            rsnew!level = level
            rsnew!PARENTPART = rs.Fields("PARENTPART")
            rsnew!Route = rs.Fields("Route")
            rsnew!SequenceNum = rs.Fields("SequenceNum")
            rsnew!Component = rs.Fields("Component")
            Search_Part = rs.Fields("Component")
            If CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT PARENTPART, ROUTE, SEQUENCENUM, COMPONENT FROM TEST_BomStructure AS BOMqry WHERE PARENTPART = '" & Search_Part & "'").RecordCount > 0 Then
                Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT PARENTPART, ROUTE, SEQUENCENUM, COMPONENT FROM TEST_BomStructure AS BOMqry WHERE PARENTPART = '" & Search_Part & "'")
            End If
            rs.MoveNext
        rsnew.Update
        'Move to Back to 2nd component in Top Level?
    Loop
    
End Function


Exploding a BoM can be a very complex process. Rather than re-invent the wheel, maybe you should have a look at what is already available and adapt it to your needs. I did a quick web search and found many examples. You may want to start here: http://access.mvps.org/access/modules/mdl0027.htm

I found that, I can’t even get it to open in my version of Access.

I thought I would throw together some code to demonstrate a recursive procedure call which will explode a BoM down to all levels. Note that in the BoM table I have added a new field called Component_Is_Parent which when True indicates that the component is comprised of sub-components. This is far more efficient that doing a table lookup. I hope you find this helpful.
The following data in the BoM table (tblBOM) is what I used to test the code:
ParentPart Route SequenceNum Component Component_Is_Parent
PN1234     A     1           CMP001    False
PN1234     A     2           CMP002    False
PN1234     A     3           CMP003    True
PN1234     A     4           CMP004    False
CMP003     A     1           SCMP001   False
CMP003     A     2           SCMP002   False
CMP003     A     3           SCMP003   False
CMP003     A     4           SCMP004   True
CMP003     A     5           SCMP005   False
CMP003     A     6           SCMP006   False
SCMP004    A     1           SCMP2001  False
SCMP004    A     2           SCMP2002  False
SCMP004    A     3           SCMP2003  False

Put the following code into a module. Use procedure sBuildPart to run the code:
Option Explicit

Public db As DAO.Database

' Main procedure to explode the BOM to all levels
Sub sBuildPart()

  Set db = CurrentDb

  ' Clear the output table
  With DoCmd
    .SetWarnings False
    .RunSQL "DELETE * FROM tblBOMResult;"
    .SetWarnings True
  End With

  Call sExplodeBOM("PN1234", 0)

  Set db = Nothing

End Sub

' This procedure is called recursively to explode the entire BOM to all levels.
Sub sExplodeBOM(strSearch_Part As String, lngLevel As Long)
   
  Dim rs    As DAO.Recordset
  Dim rsNew As DAO.Recordset
  
  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT ParentPart, Route, SequenceNum, Component, Component_Is_Parent FROM tblBOM WHERE ParentPart = '" & strSearch_Part & "';")
  Set rsNew = db.OpenRecordset("tblBOMResult")

  With rs

    ' Only process if we have a populated recordset.
    If Not .BOF Then
      .MoveFirst

      Do While Not .EOF

        ' Write to the output table
        rsNew.AddNew
          rsNew!ParentPart = !ParentPart
          rsNew!Route = !Route
          rsNew!SequenceNum = !SequenceNum
          rsNew!Component = !Component
          rsNew!level = lngLevel
        rsNew.Update

        If !Component_Is_Parent = True Then
          ' Component is flagged as a parent item. Drill down into BOM.
          Call sExplodeBOM(!Component, lngLevel + 1)
        End If

        .MoveNext

      Loop

    End If

    .Close
    rsNew.Close

  End With

  Set rs = Nothing
  Set rsNew = Nothing

End Sub


You have several options. One, however, won't do and that is a recursive query using Access SQL only; Access can't be fooled and will claim about a circular reference. Your only chance is to create a query resolving a limited number of levels only, say, 8 or 10.
But you can cover the recursive call in a domain aggregate function like DLookup(). This is, however, very slow as DLookup() calling the query will run for each and every record. For more than some dozens of records this will most likely be unacceptable.
For an unlimited number of levels, the fastest way I've found is to create a lookup function which walks the tree for each record. This can output either the level of the record or a compound key build by the key of the record and all keys above.
As the lookup function will use the same recordset for every call, you can make it static, and (for Jet) you can improve further by using Seek to locate the records.
Here's an example which will give you an idea:
Function RecursiveLookup(ByVal lngID As Long) As String

  Static dbs      As Database
  Static tbl      As TableDef
  Static rst      As Recordset

  Dim lngLevel    As Long
  Dim strAccount  As String

  If dbs Is Nothing Then
    ' For testing only.
    ' Replace with OpenDatabase of backend database file.
    Set dbs = CurrentDb()
    Set tbl = dbs.TableDefs("tblAccount")
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(tbl.Name, dbOpenTable)
  End If

  With rst
    .Index = "PrimaryKey"
    While lngID > 0
      .Seek "=", lngID
      If Not .NoMatch Then
        lngLevel = lngLevel + 1
        lngID = !MasterAccountFK.Value
        If lngID > 0 Then
          strAccount = str(!AccountID) & strAccount
        End If
      Else
        lngID = 0
      End If
    Wend
    ' Leave recordset open.
    ' .Close
  End With

'  Don't terminate static objects.
'  Set rst = Nothing
'  Set tbl = Nothing
'  Set dbs = Nothing

'  Alternative expression for returning the level.
'  (Adjust vartype of return value of function.) '  RecursiveLookup = lngLevel ' As Long
  RecursiveLookup = strAccount

End Function

This assumes a local table (of the dbs object) with a primary key ID and a foreign (master) key pointing to the parent record - and a top level record (not used) with a visible key (AccountID) of 0.
Now your tree will be nicely shown almost instantaneously using a query like this where Account will be the visible compound key:
  SELECT
    *, RecursiveLookup([ID]) AS Account
  FROM
    tblAccount
  WHERE
    (AccountID > 0)
  ORDER BY
    RecursiveLookup([ID]);


A slightly modified code of the original code:
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub MakeBom(ByVal Search_Part$, Optional level As Integer = 0)
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsnew As DAO.Recordset

    If level = 0 Then CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM TEST_BomResult;"

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT PARENTPART, ROUTE, SEQUENCENUM, COMPONENT FROM TEST_BomStructure AS BOMqry WHERE PARENTPART = '" & Search_Part & "'")
    Set rsnew = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TEST_BomResult")
    
    Do Until rs.EOF
        rsnew.AddNew
            rsnew!level = level
            rsnew!PARENTPART = Space(level * 2 + 2) & rs.Fields("PARENTPART")
            rsnew!Route = rs.Fields("Route")
            rsnew!SequenceNum = rs.Fields("SequenceNum")
            rsnew!Component = Space(level * 2 + 2) & rs.Fields("Component")
            Search_Part = rs.Fields("Component")
            MakeBom rs.Fields("Component"), level + 1
            rs.MoveNext
        rsnew.Update
    Loop
End Sub

Test the code with:
MakeBom "PN1234"
